# RESTful API Best Practices searching for SSN

Tags: rest

This is a pretty simple question, I hope; I'm working on a RESTful API, but one of the endpoints allows you to get a person, and is searchable by social security number.

I'm a bit leary of putting this into a fully RESTful interface since we then end up with open query string like 
`https://service.com/person?ssn=xxxxxxxxx`

Seems bad... what's the best practice with searching an API using very sensitive data?

Comment: Sensitive data should NEVER be put in a GET request. Ever. Hash it and put it in a POST body.

Comment: So you would do a /index request with a POST instead?

Comment: Add a POST endpoint to`/person` or create a `/person/search` endpoint

Comment: One way would be doing some kind of encryption of your sensitive data and pass it in the request body.

Comment: So you're both suggesting I break the pure REST standards for this case... I'm good with that answer I guess, just was wondering if there's a capital-R Rest way to handle it.

Comment: @user12447201 the RESTful resource would be `/people` and `/people/search`. Resources are plural.